# Interpret precision and recall curve

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

I am evaluating a classification model and I am using the PR curve because of my highly imbalanced dataset (negative class is the 5%).

In the end I'm comparing the training PR curve and the test PR curve. I got this graph:
[image]

I've also calculated PR AUC: after training it is equal to 1.0, after test it is equal to 0.9931231201460553. If the difference between areas is just 0.006876879853944695, why in the graph the curves are so different?
How can I interpret these curves?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a big discrepancy between your two PR AUC figures and the curve to me. The precision axis runs from 0.986 to 1.0 and recall from 0 to 1. If you plotted both these with both axis limits being 0 to 1 the difference would look much smaller.

Comment: Okay I'll try. Also is it normal to have a flat PR curve?

Comment: The flat PR curve and PR AUC of 1 indicates your model classified the training data perfectly.